# How to extract date form data frame column?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame like that:

```
    month       items
0   1962-01-01  589
1   1962-02-01  561
2   1962-03-01  640
3   1962-04-01  656
4   1962-05-01  723
```

I need to get year or month from this data frame and create array, but I don't know how to do that.

expected result:

```
years = [1962, 1962, 1962....]
monthes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5.....]
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry is this `pandas`? If the month column is dtype datetime then you can just do `years = df['month'].dt.year.tolist()` and for `months = df['month'].dt.month.tolist()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is `pandas` you may need to convert the month column to dtype `datetime` and then you can use `.dt` accessor for the year and month attributes:

```
In [33]:
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'])
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 2 columns):
month    5 non-null datetime64[ns]
items    5 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
memory usage: 120.0 bytes

In [35]:
years = df['month'].dt.year.tolist()
months = df['month'].dt.month.tolist()
print(years)
print(months)

[1962, 1962, 1962, 1962, 1962]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```